# Can I set a div's background to be two different images filled to 2 different %'s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After looking through W3Schools I'm still not sure if this is possible or not.

The idea is to have the div be a progress bar. (Yes, I am aware of jQuery UI's progress bar.) I would like it to start out 100% filled with one background-image, but overtime have it fill from 0%/100% to 100%/0%.

I see that it is possible to have multiple background images specified using css: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_multiple

but I am not sure how to extend that logic to having only % widths. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the width of a background image. But the solution is easy. The div by itself is the progress bar at 0% (so has the unloaded background image), then have another div inside that which is the actual progress (which animates from 0% to 100% and has the loaded background image). So you animate the width of the div *inside* the progress bar to represent progress.

Comment: This is the way I typically do it... no need for any z-index either.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a few examples that use a span within a div:

http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/

it's not using images (just CSS3), but you could easily update it have background images on both the span and the div.  CSS3 does allow multiple background images (http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) but I'm not really sure if it's the best use for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`, it's possible to overlay one image with another; you'll have to be careful with the [z-index](http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), though. You'll then be able to animate the width of the image you want to act as the 'progress meter' using jQuery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, like this (assuming your progress meter image width starts out at 0px and will end up at 100px):

```
$("#progress_meter").animate( {"width": "100px"}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can set another div on top of the initial div and have a higher z-index property.

For example, on the code below, div-a will be on top of div-b:

```
.div-a {
    with: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.div-b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```